# ERROR DEP0700: ERROR IN APPMODEL VERSION

Tags: visual-studio-2012

WHILE DEPLOYING aPP IN VISUAL STUDIO 2012 EXPRESS.I AM GETTING THE FOLLOWING ERROR:

Error   1   Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. Windows cannot install package 2a787e3d-dd2e-476a-a012-a7ab38019030 because this package requires a higher Windows version. The package requested Windows version 6.2 with AppModel version 1, while the current Windows version is 6.2 with AppModel version 0. (0x80073cfd) App1

MY OS IS WINDOWS 8 RELEASE PREVIEW

Comment: All caps is generally not a good way to get a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install Visual Studio release version on Windows 8 RP. See [this](http://blog.nwcadence.com/installing-visual-studio-2012-rtm-on-windows-8-rc-2/) post.